# Unity | Как настроить UI Scroll Rect что бы он не прокручивался бесконечно

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

У меня есть элемент **QuestionsScrollPanel**, на нём весит ScrollRect и он содержит контент с объектами, которые и нужно листать. У **ScrollRect** есть свойство **Mode**. Мне по сути подходи мод **Unrestricted**, но у него есть проблема, он не ограничивает скролинг и я могу листать там, где контент уже закончился. Что мне сделать что б всё работало как я сформулировал в вопросе?

[Видео](https://youtu.be/WxLm3I3sQ88) для наглядности

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что вам нужен режим Unrestricted?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я не знаю какой лучше, но просто остальные не дают возможности листать нормально в принципе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верните тип на **Elastic**.

Ваш косяк в том, что вы поставили `Ancor present` объекта `Content` на `stretch/stretch`, а должен быть `top/stretch`.

Из-за этого вы не можете установить размер `Rect`, который и определяет границу скроллинга.

Comment: Ничего не поменялось https://youtu.be/MHVI9BvObZw